# Sum selected rows to a new row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to add a new row `total` in a dataframe where I am trying to add the values for that row which has value like `Mazda`.Below is the df I am using.

```
df <- data.frame(month = c("mazda 3", "mazda cx5", "mazda 6","mazda miata","honda civic","honda accord"),
             april = c(.1,.2,.3,.3,.4,.5),
             may = c(.3,.4,.5,.2,.1,.5),
             june = c(.2,.1,.5,.1,.2,.3))


d2<- df %>% mutate(total == (rowsum(df[-1], df[rownames(month) %like% "Mazda"])))
```

Output should be :

```
df_out <- data.frame(month = c("mazda 3", "mazda cx5", "mazda 6","mazda miata","honda civic","honda accord","total_mazda"),
                 april = c(.1,.2,.3,.3,.4,.5,.8),
                 may = c(.3,.4,.5,.2,.1,.5,1.4),
                 june = c(.2,.1,.5,.1,.2,.3,.9))
```

Comment: I think you need `i1 <- grep("mazda", df$month);colSums(df[i1, -1])`

Comment: @SNT can you provide a sample of output?

Comment: Also be aware that you should use a single `=` and not a double `==`, which is a logical test. Or perhaps just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `sum` of the numeric columns in `summarise_at` while subsetting the values based on the 'mazda' substring in 'month', create a 'month' column and bind with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  summarise_at(2:4, funs(sum(.[str_detect(month, 'mazda')]))) %>% 
  mutate(month = 'Total') %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

Comment: Since we are adding column 2:4 you have it that ways. what if  the no of columns keep on increasing.

Comment: @SNT  You can change that number to any number `2:ncol(.)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply(df, 2, ...)` to cycle through the columns with a `grepl` mask for mazda in the first column.

I used some `bind_(rows|cols)` trickery to get the data frame in the right format.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(month = c("mazda 3", "mazda cx5", "mazda 6","mazda miata","honda civic","honda accord"),
             april = c(.1,.2,.3,.3,.4,.5),
             may = c(.3,.4,.5,.2,.1,.5),
             june = c(.2,.1,.5,.1,.2,.3))

df_out <- bind_rows(
  df %>% as_data_frame(),
  data_frame(month = "total_mazda") %>%
    bind_cols(
      apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)],
        2,
        function(x, y = grepl(".*(m|M)azda.*", df[[1]])) sum(x[y])
      ) %>%
        as.list() %>%
        as_data_frame()))
```